# Why CanExecute only get called when it's initialized in the constructor of the view model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged, icommand

I have a `Command` property, with this definition in the view model:

```
public RelayCommand SaveCommand => new RelayCommand(OnSave, CanSave);
```

whenever the `ErrorsChanged` of the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` is fired, `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` is called in the `RelayCommand` class, to enable/disable the button:

```
public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

the two delegates of the command are set in the constructor:

```
public RelayCommand(Action executeMethod, Func<bool> canExecuteMethod)
        {
            _TargetExecuteMethod = executeMethod;
            _TargetCanExecuteMethod = canExecuteMethod;
        }
```

but when the error state changed (when `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` is called) the `CanSave` method doesn't get called, after a while I changed the `Command` initialization way to be set in the constructor instead:

```
    public AddEditCustomerViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(OnSave, CanSave);
    }
    public RelayCommand SaveCommand {get;}
```

and it works! but why?

Comment: You say that *`CanSave` method doesnt get called* but we cannot tell when and who will call it. Also, what does `CanExecuteChanged` method do? As it stands now, its hard to figure out from the code that you have posted, what the issue could be. In other words we do not have enough info or cose to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize the `SaveCommad` in the view model's constructor, it only run once when the view model is initialized, but When you define `SaveCommand` using:

```
public RelayCommand SaveCommand => new RelayCommand(OnSave, CanSave);
```

You are actually doing:

```
public RelayCommand SaveCommand {
    get {
        return new RelayCommand(OnSave, CanSave);
    }
}
```

In such case Whenever the getter of `SaveCommand` is called, it returns a new instance of `RelayCommand`. So when the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` is called, it may not be the same object that's currently binding to the UI, hence failed to update the state